# Drag and drop from one place to multiple another place

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular-material

I need to make **Drag and Drop** list with **angular material**. 
This is ok when I have one list, but now I need to have one multiple lists.

For example, I have one **drag** list with user roles (admin, user, view), and I need to have multiple users **drop** place, where I can drag&drop user roles. But, roles in **DRAG** list is always visible.

Here is an example of what I want, but I need help on how to make multiple **drop** list, depending on how many users I get from API and all this list need to get data from sam **DRAG** list, and also I need to have options to remove users role. Of course, on submit I need to send all this data to server

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-drag-copy-jervpt

EDIT:

with the help of @Campanita Belen I get to drag roles from one place to multiple drop zone.

But still don't find a solution on how to remove the added role, and how to collect data separately for every user tp JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's actually very simple, in the drop event i'm pushing the item that just got removed from the list, also checking that i'm not adding it to the same list, leaving you the link with the code! 
Hope this helps!!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6

Also check the documentation of the drag & drop...

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Comment: this i great.... only one thing, I need to drag and drop items only from `ROLES`. How to disable to add role from `LIST 1` to `LIST 2` etc?  and also remove roles from List? Thnx... this will be accepted mesasage

Comment: You can play with the values in the attribute [cdkDropListConnectedTo] in each list in the html, i changed the code with what you asked, check again this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6

Comment: Cool, i figuret out how to disable to add role from LIST 1 to LIST 2...